# Java HTTP POST request to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, post, httprequest

I have a Spring MVC Controller with the following method definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value="SaveReading.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
protected void saveReading(Reading reading) throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.debug("Received reading for id: " + reading.getMonitorId());
}
```

I need to send data to this controller from a Java program, by producing a `POST` HTTP request.

I tried the following code:

```
try {

    url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebApp/SaveReading.htm");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    logger.error("Malformed URL ", e);
    return;
}
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    logger.debug("Opened Connection. " + conn.getURL());
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.connect();

    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());        
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error setting up URL connection: ", e);
}

String data = "";
try {
    data = URLEncoder.encode("monitorId", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("timeStamp", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(""+new Date().getTime(), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    logger.error("Encoding problem ", e);
}
System.out.println("Sending HTTP message: \n" + data);
// Send data
try {
    writer.write(data);
    writer.flush();
```

The Java code failed to reach the controller.
Is the URL I'm using is the correct one, assuming that my web project is "WebApp"?

- `web.xml`:

  ```
  <display-name>Web Application</display-name>  

  <servlet>  
      <servlet-name>ReadingsServlet</servlet-name>  
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>  
      <servlet-name>ReadingsServlet</servlet-name>  
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/ReadingsServlet-servlet.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```
- `ReadingsServlet-servlet.xml`:

  ```
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.familycare"/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="miscillaneous.property_placeholder" /> 

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
  ```

Comment: Just in case, does it work with a 'public' modifier for the method?

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: I tried changing to public. It didn't help.

Comment: Also, I forgot the Tomcat port in the URL, but adding it didn't work either.

Comment: If you paste http://localhost:8080/WebApp/SaveReading.htm into a browser, do you see the request hit in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: Let's see your `Reading` class.

Comment: Yes. If I put the URL in a browser I see a GET request.

Comment: I double checked that all the field names in the Reading class match exactly the name of the parameters in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

It does work now.
I'm not sure what caused the problem before.